# SWT: Table lost selection

Tags: java, swt

I have a Table like below, but when table lost focus (click some button for example), selection lost too. How to avoid this ?

```
Table table = new Table(group, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
table.setLinesVisible(true);
table.setHeaderVisible(true);

table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
        onSelection();
    }
});
```

row selected:
[image: selected]

selection lost:
[image: selection lost]

Comment: So `onSelection()` is called when the table loose focus?

Comment: Yhmm... no, `onSelection()` is called only in this adapter.

Comment: Do you still remember what windows OS you're using? This problem only happens to me on windows server 2008, is it the same for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, so your table does not *show* the selected row when the table does not have focus? That is a well known problem in several different editions of Windows.

*Please Note*: It is not a SWT problem, but simply the way some editions of Windows work!!

Comment: Really? What can I do to show selection on all editions ? Set some colors or something ? Maybe use something instead of Table ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background and foreground colour of the selected table item. See here [Highlighting swt table row on focus lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614209/highlighting-swt-table-row-on-focus-lost/18013138#18013138)