# Highlighting swt table row on focus lost

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am facing the same problem mentioned here [SWT: Table lost selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549842/swt-table-lost-selection) . I am using ubuntu 12.04 NOT windows. Is there any way to highlight the selected row of a SWT table even after focus lost. I tried adding focus listener to the table and in focus lost I changed the selected item background colour and on focus gain resets the background colour.  See the code.

```
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            System.out.println("table focus los");
            TableItem item = fileListTable
                    .getItem(fileListTable.getSelectionIndex());
            prevSelItemBackground = item.getBackground();
            item.setBackground(soureWindow.getSelectionBackground());//Some random colour
            System.out.println(fileListTable.getSelectionIndex());
        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            System.out.println("table focus gain");
            TableItem item = fileListTable
                    .getItem(fileListTable.getSelectionIndex());
            item.setBackground(prevSelItemBackground);
            System.out.println(fileListTable.getSelectionIndex());
        }
```

But it is not working. Is there any other solution/workaround for this?

Comment: Can you remove the content of `focusGained` and see if the row is colored at all.

Comment: Just tried it at home on my linux machine. Even if the `Table` loses the focus, the row is still highlighted. Can you maybe add a screenshot of your problem?

Comment: Got a fix for this problem See the code is corrected:

Comment: If you found a solution, please post it as an answer, not in the comment. If you want to add information to your question [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17614209/edit) it.

Comment: I think It is not possible to answer as this question was asked by myself. I am not getting answer window for this question.Can I add the solution in question itself?

Comment: You should be able to answer your own question. Refresh the page and make sure that the answer window at the bottom of the page is not there. If so, you can add the answer to your question and I can post it, if that's ok with you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below snippet can be used:

```
    this.fileListTable.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

    @Override
    public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        // Nothing to do
    }

    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

        int selectionIndex = fileListTable.getSelectionIndex();                                                             
        TableItem[] items = fileListTable.getItems();
        TableItem newItem;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        String first = items[i].getText(0);
        String second = items[i].getText(1);
        String third = items[i].getText(2);
        items[i].dispose();
        newItem = new TableItem(fileListTable, SWT.NONE);
        newItem.setText(new String[] { first, second, third });
        if (i == selectionIndex) {
            newItem.setForeground(soureWindow.getSelectionForeground());//Or Anyother color
            newItem.setBackground(soureWindow.getSelectionBackground());//Or Anyother color
        } else {
            newItem.setForeground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));//Default foreground color
            newItem.setBackground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));//Default background color
        }
        }                
    }
    });
```

Its is working fine for me but not tested on larger data.