# User Selection getting lost in StyledText when fouse lost

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, swt-awt

I am using StyledText(org.eclipse.swt.custom) in UI.

The problem currently i am facing is selection(Selected text in StyledText)  is getting lost  when focus moved away(EX:Some button clicked)  from the StyledText.

Is there any way to retain selection ?

Comment: Can't reproduce that at all. Tested it here and the `StyledText` maintains its selection on both loss of focus of the text as well as loss of focus of the `Shell`.

Comment: I think you are also facing the same problem mentioned in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614209/highlighting-swt-table-row-on-focus-lost. Please check my answer to this.

Comment: Ok . I guess in my application some thing need to checked because i  paint-event is getting called when i loose the focus .